# SQL inline variable assignment

Tags: sql, t-sql, variables

I have a SQL statement that determines the number of days between two dates.  If the difference is negative, the statement needs to select 0.  This statement works but I was wondering if it is possible to assign the value of `datediff("D",GETDATE(),dbo.tblKBX_Reward.validdate)` to a @ variable so I don't have to call it twice.

```
SELECT CASE 
WHEN datediff("D",GETDATE(),dbo.tblKBX_Reward.validdate) < 0  THEN 0
ELSE datediff("D",GETDATE(),dbo.tblKBX_Reward.validdate)
END from ...
```

Please don't ask why I am calculating this value using SQL instead of in code.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could move the case statement inside the calculation, like this:

```
Select DateDiff("D", GetDate(), Case When YourColumn > GetDate() 
                                     Then YourColumn 
                                     Else GetDate() 
                                     End)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can write a higher level `SELECT` something like this.

```
SELECT CASE 
       WHEN diff_date < 0  THEN 0
       ELSE diff_date
       END 
FROM (
     SELECT datediff("D",GETDATE(),dbo.tblKBX_Reward.validdate) AS diff_date
     from ...
     )
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are selecting more than one row, then you can't assign it to a variable. In your case, you can use a derived table or a CTE:

```
SELECT  Cols, 
        CASE 
        WHEN DiffDates < 0  THEN 0
        ELSE DiffDates
        END DiffDates
FROM (  SELECT Cols, datediff("D",GETDATE(),dbo.tblKBX_Reward.validdate) DiffDates
        FROM dbo.tblKBX_Reward) A
```

Or:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT Cols, datediff("D",GETDATE(),dbo.tblKBX_Reward.validdate) DiffDates
    FROM dbo.tblKBX_Reward
)

SELECT  Cols, 
        CASE 
        WHEN DiffDates < 0  THEN 0
        ELSE DiffDates
        END DiffDates
FROM CTE
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
  CASE WHEN daydiff < 0 THEN 0 ELSE daydiff END
FROM your tables/joins
CROSS APPLY (
  SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY, GETDATE(), dbo.tblKBX_Reward.validdate)
) x (daydiff)
WHERE …
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a CTE:

```
WITH cte_dateDiffs (RewardId, dateDiff) 
AS (
   SELECT RewardId, datediff("D",GETDATE(), validdate) FROM dbo.tblKBX_Reward
)
SELECT CASE 
   WHEN dd.dateDiff < 0 THEN 0 
   ELSE dd.dateDiff 
END
FROM dbo.tblKBX_Reward r
INNER JOIN cte_dateDiffs dd ON r.RewardId == dd.RewardId
...
```